# Get Black and White 2 BIT image using Emgu CV

Tags: c#, emgucv

Hi have a image which I need to convert into black and white and in 2 bit depth.

I tried following and it generates an image with 8 bit. Don't see any option to generate image of 2 bit.

```
Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, Single> image = new Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, Single>("test.jpg");
```

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

In emgucv you have the following image Depth

Byte, SByte, Single (float), Double, UInt16, Int16, Int32 (int)
(from [emgucv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Image_Depth))

You do not have an 2 bit depth. 
But you can make an images that looks like an 2 bit image like this:

```
var theImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(@"d:\temp\lena.jpg");
        for (int i = theImage.Rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = theImage.Cols - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if(theImage.Data[i,j,0]>byte.MaxValue/2)
                {
                        theImage.Data[i, j, 0] = byte.MaxValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    theImage.Data[i, j, 0] = 0;
                }

            }
        }
```